# Can't load WMS service, "Failed to parse capabilities"

Tags: qgis, wms, getcapabilities

Using QGIS 3.8.1 and trying to load the QLG Gov base imagery WMS layer. It was working perfectly fine but then suddenly just stopped working and gave the message "Failed to parse capabilities". Tried changing the CRS's, but that didn't help.

The server I'm trying to load is "https://gisservices.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/services/Imagery/QldBase_AllUsers/ImageServer/WMSServer"

Anyone know what's going on?

You can probably tell I'm new to using GIS software, but willing to learn and get there!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the service doesn't allow GetCapabilities requests. So QGIS doesn't know how to construct a query

https://gisservices.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/services/Imagery/QldBase_AllUsers/ImageServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

Gives:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
    <ServiceException code="AccessDenied">
    GetCapabilities Operation is not enabled for the service.
    </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

It appears that the URL has changed, the WMS is now at:

> https://gisservices.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/services/Imagery/QldBase_AllUsers/MapServer/WMSServer?