# WMS link only works in ArcGIS Online not ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro or QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcmap, wms

I have a property layer from a WMS link `https://ext-geodata-nationella.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/rest/services/LM/lst_lm_infoklick/MapServer` I want to load into my maps but I can only seem to load it properly in ArcGIS Online, not ArcMap 10.8.1, ArcGIS Pro 2.6.3 nor QGIS 3.22.11. In QGIS it says, "Failed to parse capabilities".

I read the answer to the same question here ([Can't load WMS service, "Failed to parse capabilities"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342760/cant-load-wms-service-failed-to-parse-capabilities)) and they said "the service doesn't allow GetCapabilities requests."

I must be running into a different error though if I can still load it in ArcGIS Online. Are there some settings I'm missing when adding the WMS link to any offline maps? Or is this link only available in an online map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no WMS associated with that resource, (which is why you have the error correctly reporting that there is no WMS Capabilities response).

You may be able to add it to QGIS using the Add ArcGIS REST Server layer option.

Comment: To elaborate: what the server serves is not a WMS. It is (probably) a ArcGIS REST service. You can load it in ArcGIS Online because they handle ArcGIS REST services without you specifying it as a ArcGIS REST service. For the Desktop GIS you need to specify the correct layer type.

Comment: I think you were right and I was able to load it as an ArcGIS REST server layer. I added the layers, but was not able to see the actual data. It is a step further though because I can see there is attribute data in the layer settings.

I've changed the symbology, checked rendering settings, zoomed in very close (it would only show when zooming in on ArcGIS Online). Not sure now, any other ideas?

Comment: Data is scale layered ~ `Min Scale: 100000`